# Labels not showing on radio button inside a Flow (called by lightning component)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow, radio-button, screen-flow

I encountered a most wierd behavior and can't explain it.
I have a screen flow which I call from a lightning component, and on the screen of the flow the radio buttons labels are not displayed.

[image]

the radio buttons are comming from a picklist field on account, really standard stuff

[image]

The wierd thing is next: i call the same flow from another lightning component and the radio buttons are working fine! (see below)

[image]

So both of the flows are called the same way (from a lightning component button) see below:

1/ Working LC (showing label):

Component

```
   <lightning:flow aura:id="flowId" onstatuschange="{!c.handleFlow}" />
```

Controller/Helper:

```
handleFlow : function(component, helper, event) {
    var flow = component.find("flowId");
            // Put input variable values
            var inputVariables = [     
            ];
            flow.startFlow("test", inputVariables);  
},
```

1/ not Working LC (not showing label):

Component

```
   <lightning:flow aura:id="flowId2" onstatuschange="{!c.handleFlow}" />
```

Controller/Helper:

```
handleFlow : function(component, helper, event) {
    var flow = component.find("flowId2");
            // Put input variable values
            var inputVariables = [     
            ];
            flow.startFlow("test", inputVariables);  
},
```

As you can see the code is the same, I checked the Profiles but fields are availables. 
Has any of you already encoutered this kind of error? 
At this point and it has been a long time since it happened I have absolutly no clue what could be the cause of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an idea, did you check that the actual text it's not there? Inspect in the browser. May be some CSS is affecting the text and making it white, so it is there but you can't see it.

Comment: Damn, it was some CSS! 

I feel dumb that i didn't though about it in the first place!

Anyway big thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad to hear that you found what´s wrong!